# Multiple WebViews with Phonegap on iOS

Tags: css, ios, html, cordova, uiwebview

Is it possible to create Multiple (overlapping) WebViews in an iOS only Phonegap app, as shown in this image:

http://cl.ly/GnvU

I want to do this to have a scrolling content area inside the application, and I find methods like iScroll and jScrollPane too hacky for this type of usage. Is there any other way to achieve native scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Check out what Randy McMillan has been doing with using Cordova Cleaver - 
https://github.com/RandyMcMillan/ModalCleaverView2

It's not exact... but pretty close to what you're looking for - you'll need to adjust some things of course but this should point you in the right direction!

Comment: Looks like there's a fork here: https://github.com/DrewDahlman/ModalCleaverView2 ...but it's iOS-only and 3 years stale.